# Can not execute Shell commands with PHP-Script

Tags: php, shell, root

Currently I'm working on a PHP script that can execute shell commands on a linux root server.

I want to give any user with the right password (htacces) the permission to execute this script (it´s for OpenVPN client creation). When i jump to the plesk interface to execute the PHP script in file data manager, i get an internal server error 500. I already changed the permission of the PHP script to 777 for testing purposes.

I also controlled the php.ini to check if shell_exec/proc_open/exec are on the banned function list.

How can i configure the server/php script to have root permissions on the script?

Is it possible to Log-in with root priviliges when exceuting shell commands with a php script?

Thanks in advance.

Have a nice day.

EDIT: The current code is:

```
shell_exec('cd ' . $path-openvpn-ca);
shell_exec('source ./vars');


$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin read by child
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout written to by child
    2 => array("file", "error.log", "a") // stderr
);
$process = proc_open($path_openvpn-ca. "/build-key.sh LC_1234", $descriptorspec, $pipes);
if (is_resource($process)) {
    fwrite($pipes[0], PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL. "." . PHP_EOL. "." PHP_EOL. "y" . PHP_EOL. "y". PHP_EOL);
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    $output = $pipes[1]; // $pipes[0] is the input and $pipes[2] is the error output
}
```

Comment: "When i jump to the plesk interface to execute the PHP script in file data manager, i get an internal server error 500" - a more detailed error should be in PHP error log: what does that error message say? (your server host should probably give you a way to read the error log)

Comment: Hello, where can i find that error log? Is there a standard path for it? Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot define a variable with a dash caracter. `$path-openvpn-ca`  is a substration for php. You have a syntax error in your script, try `php -l ` for checking the syntax

Comment: It could be in various places; check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel . Also, for development, it might be useful to show the errors directly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?rq=1

Comment: @Arno thanks, i did not notice that. 

Piskvor thanks, ill check that out.

Comment: I fixed it. The internal server error was because of different syntax errors.. 

I can now execute my proc_open function to build keys. But the error log (from proc_open pipe2) show the following:
sh: 1: /root/openvpn-ca/build-key.sh: Permission denied
sh: 1: /root/openvpn-ca/build-key.sh: Permission denied
But both the build-key/ php script have 777 permission for testing purpose.

Comment: try `chmod +x   /root/openvpn-ca/build-key.sh`

Comment: Hello, the permission bug is now fixed! Thanks! 

But the current error log i get is : 
/openvpn-ca/build-key.sh: not found - but the path is right.

Comment: You said it was `/root/openvpn-ca/build-key.sh` in your other comment?

Comment: This problem is now solved. 

I will create a new question for another issue. Thanks for your help.